# what is the use of allprojects{} when root project does not have Gradle build file?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

As per gradlew 8.1.1 documentation https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html, in multi project setup, the recommended project structure,  root project does not have any code nor gradle build file but only setttings.gradle file. What is the use of 'allprojects{}' section in that case? which file would have this section? is this sub project which have further subprojects?

allprojects{} is not useful and it does not cover 'all' projects if it is inside a subproject's gradle build file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is no longer recommended to have common code in root project. `allprojects{}` is not needed.

Instead of `allprojects{}`, it is recommend to use `buildSrc`.

`buildSrc` allows to define multiple common build logic.

Check "Use buildSrc to abstract imperative logic" in link below.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:build_sources